# SQL Pivot Table Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  INT_AUX_CONTACT.CONTACT_VISIBILITY_IND,
     INT_USER.ACCOUNT_NM

FROM (INT_USER 
INNER JOIN INT_AUX_CONTACT_COLLECTION      ON "INT_USER"."USER_ID"="INT_AUX_CONTACT_COLLECTION".IA_USER_ID) 
INNER JOIN INT_AUX_CONTACT  ON INT_AUX_CONTACT_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_ID=INT_AUX_CONTACT.COLLECTION_ID
WHERE INT_AUX_CONTACT_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_TYP_ID=1 AND INT_AUX_CONTACT.DELETED_IND=0
and ACTIVE_IND=1
```

Which returns the following result sample:

```
contact_visibility_ind|account_nm
1                      HR05
2                      HR05
3                      HR05
3                      HR05
2                      HR05
1                      CH10
2                      CH10
3                      CH10
4                      CH10
0                      CH10
2                      CH10
```

I would like to produce a pivot table with a result table that looks like:

```
           0  1  2  3  4
CH10  0  1  2  2  0
HR05  1  1  2  1  1
```

But every time I attempt the pivot function I come up with syntax errors.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
(sorry there are no gridlines in my tables!)

Comment: your aliasing seems redundant to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: the aliasing is completely redundant, I inherited the query. I'll amend and republish the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of how you came to your final derivation of pivot table. I've assumed that you want to count the number of each occurrence(possibly `CH10` and `HR05` should be swapped in the table?)

```
SELECT account_nm, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT * 
 FROM 
 ResultOfQuery
) x
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(contact_visibility_ind)
  FOR contact_visibility_ind IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) y;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f323/14)

Just paste your query into the `SELECT * FROM ResultOfQuery` placeholder.

Comment: Perfect. Your assumptions about PT derivation was correct. Thank you sir.